# Cannot perform prop function onClick when usnig stateless functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, stateless

I can't seem to get my modal button to run the function I have passed into it.

Am I missing something?

**Dashboard.js**

```
const Dashboard = () => {

    let show = false;

    const showModal = () => {
        console.log('showing modal');
    };

    const hideModal = () => {
        console.log('closing modal');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is the dashboard</h1>
            <button type="button" onClick={showModal}>Open</button>
            <Modal handleClose={hideModal} show={show}/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**Modal.js**

```
const Modal = (handleClose, show, children) => {
    const showHideClass = show ? 'show-modal' : 'hide-modal';

    return (
        <div className={showHideClass}>
            <h1>This is my modal!</h1>
            <p>{children}</p>
            <button onClick={handleClose}>Close</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

I had the warning: `Expected 'onClick' listener to be a function, instead got a value of 'object' type.`, so I changed the `onClick` in **modal.js** to `() => handleClose` which dismissed the warning, however nothing happened when I clicked the button...

Comment: A functional component only ever expects **one** parameter: `props`. You man destructure it into several variables, but its still one single object. @noahCallaway is correct. The result  you're seeing is that `handleClose` is really the entire `props` object since its the first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Solution**

The issue you're having is you're not destructuring the props object that's passed in.

```
const Modal = (handleClose, show, children) => {
```

should instead put curly braces around the arguments

```
const Modal = ({handleClose, show, children}) => {
```

**Brief Explanation**

The props passed to a functional component are a single object with keys that correspond to the name of the object passed in. The object's shape would be:

```
{
   handleClose: [function],
   show: true,
   children: ...
}
```

To get the props, you can either have a single argument (idiomatically named `props`), and then access values from that object:

```
const Hello = (props) => {
   console.log(props.message);
}
```

Or you can use a destructuring assignment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the props in the function arguments:

```
const Hello = ({message}) => {
   console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about the destructuring! Solves my `className` issue also. The only thing I can't get to work now is the showing/hiding of the modal. I must have done something wrong :-/

Comment: `show` is hard-coded to `false`. Use `useState` and set it in your handlers.

Comment: It could be something with your `show-modal`, `hide-modal` css.

Unless you have a reason for wanting the modal to be in the DOM when it's not visible, you can also just not render the modal.

e.g.

    if (!show) { return null; }

Comment: @BrianThompson - Thanks! I'm just getting to grips with the functional method of React so there might be a few more questions coming.

Comment: @NoahCallaway - That is true - I was half going off a tutorial :-P

Comment: @NoahCallaway - Although checking the DOM as it currently is, the modal isn't present until we click the button to show it. It also disappears when we click it away.